# Using express-validator how to check value?

Tags: node.js

Below is my program.

```
.post([
   check('user_name').isEmpty().withMessage('User Name is require').not().isNumeric().withMessage('Please fill in English in User Name'),

check('user_mail').isEmpty().withMessage('Please fill in your email.'),
   
check('user_password').isEmpty().withMessage('Please fill in user password').not().isLength({ min: 8 })
    .withMessage('Passowrd Password min 8 char').matches(/[a-zA-Z]{8,30}$/).withMessage('Password need uppercase and lowcase')
 ] ,userCtrl.userPost);
```

my program want to check user enter user_name is whether null, when i use "check('user_name').isEmpty().withMessage('User Name is require')". user_mail is null. it will not show "Please fill in user password". when i add not().isEmpty(). it can show  "User Name is require".

|  | not() | no not() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_name is null | show message | no show message |
| user_name not null | show message | no show message |

i want my program check user enter data is whether null. Then, it will show message.

how check user enter password is include uppercase and lowcase?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please be exact and specific. Request you to update your post and frame your question properly.

Comment: How not clear? I want using express-validator to check value whether is null.